# Component testing approach

Tags: java, testing, functional-testing

I have a java component(standalone application) that reads a request from activemq(POJOs) and writes to TCP socket and reads the response from TCP socket and writes to activemq.

```
request -> activemq -> component -> tcp -> component -> activemq -> response
```

What is the best approach to test this component ? I do not want to depend on upstream application that writes and reads the POJO's from activemq and downstream application that reads and writes from TCP socket.

Comment: Use [mocking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mock_object) ?

Comment: Unit and integration testing. You may use a mock framework like Mockito or PowerMock + EasyMock.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I do not want to depend on upstream application that writes and reads the POJO's from activemq and downstream application that reads and writes from TCP socket.

Which means **you need to mock those external collaborators out using mocking framework**.

You will mock `activemq` and `tcp` as represented in your diagram and your `component` will be real instance.